# Is "$f$ is continuous $\Leftrightarrow$ $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed for all closed sets $A$" correct?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I was wondering if the statement "$f$ is continuous $\Leftrightarrow$ $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed for all closed sets $A$" is correct and how I could prove it. Thanks for all help.

Comment: What is your definition of continuity?

Comment: Is there an ambient space $X$ where all sets $A$ come from?

Comment: In my particular case the space was just $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: I know the definitions in terms of limits and in terms of epsilon-delta (Weierstrass).

Comment: how about the definition that $f$ is continuous if for every open set, its preimage under $f$ is also open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the "ambient" space for which the sets $A$ are coming from (note that $X$ is a possible subset that is both open and closed).  **Note:** I depend highly on the fact that $f^{-1}(X\setminus A)=X\setminus f^{-1}(A)$.  I think you should prove this fact yourself, since it's been a while since I've thought about it...

($\implies$ direction)

The definition of continuous is that $f^{-1} (B)$ is open for all open sets $B$. So proceed by way of contradiction: assume that there is a closed set $A$ such that $f^{-1}(A)$ is not closed, but $f$ is continuous.  Then $A^c$ is an open set, so 
$$f^{-1}(A^c)=f^{-1}(X\setminus A)=X \setminus f^{-1}(A) = [f^{-1}(A)]^c$$
 is open. Thus $f^{-1} (A)$ is closed.  This completes the contradiction

($\impliedby$ direction)

Assume $f^{-1}(A)$ was closed for all closed sets $A$. Then for such an $A$, we have
$$ [f^{-1}(A)]^c= X\setminus f^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(X \setminus A) = f^{-1}(A^c) $$
is open.  But we can identify any open set in $X$ as the complement $A^c$ of a closed set $A \subseteq X$.  So we have than the inverse of any open set is open, hence $f$ is continuous

Answer (score 0):

Yes, given a map $f X\rightarrow Y$ between topological spaces it is continuous iff and only if the pre-image of every closed set is closed. 
I will prove  the forward direction, the other direction follows similarly. If A in Y is closed then its complement is open. By hypothesis,  $f^{-1}(A^c)$ is open. But $f^{-1}(A^c)=f^{-1}(A)^c$ therefore the pre-image of A is closed.